# How I can set Bold for Textview text in code in android studio

Tags: textview, android

Please help me to add Bold attribute for text in textview.
For example,I use below code to set text color of textview,

```
tv_subtitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_menu_orange_text));
```

Now I want set Bold for this textview.But I don't know how I can do that?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);